# Django Queryset: join two querysets with one as a list or set

Tags: django, join, django-queryset

I have two separate querysets (A and B), with one having a foreign key relationship to the other (1 to many, where B is many). Is it possible to join the two querysets somehow, creating an object which looks something like this:

```
A: 
{
   some_field: ...,
   list_of_B: [...],
}
```

I have already found a relatively slow solution by just iterating over A's values and adding the field:

```
for i in range(len(A.values())):
    result[i] = A[i]
    result[i]['list_of_B'] = list(B.filter(fk_in_B=A[i]['id']))
```

For performance reasons I would like to do this within the querysets if possible. Is it even possible to have lists/sets in fields/columns of a queryset? If so, what would be a possible approach?

Edit: Some additional info.

The models that this is about.

A:

```py
class Scan(models.Model):
    <some unrelated fields>
```

B:

```py
class Image(models.Model):
    scan = models.ForeignKey(Scan, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    <some unrelated fields>
```

The queries I'm running:

```py
scans = Scan.objects.all() \
    .select_related(<select some FK field>);

images = Image.objects.filter(scan__in=scans.values_list('id', flat=True)) \
    .annotate(some_field=F(<some field>)) \
    .annotate(another_field=F(<another field>)) \
    .values('scan', 'some_field', 'another_field') \
    .annotate(count=Count('id')); # I want to know the amount of combinations between my values

# combining the queries inefficiently:
scans = scans.values()
result = {}
for i in range(len(scans)):
    result[i] = scans[i]
    result[i]['images'] = list(images.filter(scan=scans[i]['id']))
```

Comment: Can you share your models?

Comment: Yes, I added the models.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a case where you'd benefit from using `select_related` on your initial queryset A. That will cause it to do the join in the database and return all the data without further database hits, at the cost of a larger and more complex initial query.

If your queryset B has filters you'd need to move them into the query A as related fields - something like `.filter(image__some_property=some_val)`.

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) explain it pretty well.

If that's completely inappropriate to your situation, my fallback recommendation is to build a dict from your queryset B to index on the fk value. That will speed up your approach of iterating through A's values filtering B - that's doing a new database query each time. Assuming B isn't so large that this can't comfortably fit in memory, anyway. But it'd be better to use the join if you possibly can.

Comment: I added my models and the queries I'm running. I don't think select_related will work as the FK relation is the other way around? Maybe reversing the whole query would work...

Comment: Hmm, yeah, so you'd have to query `Image` and have it select_related on `Scan`, that's a little awkward. Probably beats running two different queries and classifying the images by scan ID but you'd want to profile - the denormalization means it'll send multiple copies of the `Image` data if I recall correctly.

Comment: It turned out that running two queries was performant enough in this case, I can imagine cases for which it is not the case though. Thanks for the input anyway!